# Webpacl resolve and Module not found error

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

Getting errors like:

```
[INFO] ERROR in ./~/redbox-react/lib/index.js
[INFO] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'error-stack-parser' in 'myPath\node_modules\redbox-react\lib'
[INFO]  @ ./~/redbox-react/lib/index.js 28:24-53
[INFO]  @ ./src/router/privateRoute.js
[INFO]  @ ./src/router/Router.js
[INFO]  @ ./src/index.js
[INFO]  @ multi webpack-hot-middleware/client ./src/index
[INFO] 
[INFO] ERROR in ./~/redbox-react/lib/index.js
[INFO] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'object-assign' in 'myPath\node_modules\redbox-react\lib'
[INFO]  @ ./~/redbox-react/lib/index.js 32:20-44
[INFO]  @ ./src/router/privateRoute.js
[INFO]  @ ./src/router/Router.js
[INFO]  @ ./src/index.js
[INFO]  @ multi webpack-hot-middleware/client ./src/index
```

My webpack.config.js file:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var jeet = require('jeet');
var nib = require('nib');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './src/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('development')
      }
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Boot React',
      template: path.join(__dirname, 'src/assets/index-template.html')
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
    modules: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      "node-modules"
    ]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            cacheDirectory: true
          }
        }
      ]
    },
      {
        test: /\.styl$/i,
        use: [
          {loader: 'style-loader'},
          {loader: 'css-loader'},
          {loader: 'stylus-loader'},
          jeet(),
          nib()
        ]
      }
      ,
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {loader: "style-loader"},
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {modules: true}
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
;
```

Have tried many tutorials but with no help. Any ideas, why I am getting these errors? I am trying to migrate from Webpack 1.x to Webpack 2.x. Have rewritten my webpack.config.js, babelrc and package.json files.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the problem was removing this part completely:

```
 resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
    modules: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      "node-modules"
    ]
  }
```